# Dynamic Loadfrom file image is giving Access vailation on Firemonkey Mobile

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I am creating Demo application that having list box and image. When I am running that application on Phone is giving me (using image1.loadfromfile('Path of Image')) segmentation 11 exception. I am not able to display image which are adding at run time on my Phone. I am using below code for dynamic loading image.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 item : TListBoxItem;
 img  : Timage;
begin
  item := TListBoxItem.Create(ListBox1);
  img := TImage.Create(item);
  with item do
  begin
    Text := 'Vikas';
    Height := 49;
    Selectable := False;
    StyleLookup := 'listboxitemnodetail';
    img.Align := TAlignLayout.Left;
   end;
    img.MultiResBitmap.Items[0].Bitmap.LoadFromFile('path image in .png format');
    item.AddObject(img); 
    listbox1.addobject(item);
end;
```

How to load image dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the [`img.MultiResBitmap.Add()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.MultiResBitmap.TFixedMultiResBitmap.Add) method before you can access `img.MultiResBitmap.Items[0]`:

> Creates a new TCustomBitmapItem bitmap item and adds it to the Items array.

For example:

```
img.MultiResBitmap.Add;
// now you can use img.MultiResBitmap.Items[0] as needed...
```

Alternatively:

```
var
  bmp: TFixedBitmapItem;
begin
  ...
  bmp := img.MultiResBitmap.Add;
  // use bmp as needed...
  ...
end;
```

If you do not actually need multi-resolution images, use the `img.Bitmap` property instead:

```
img.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(...);
```